# Generate buttons or clickable area

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I want to generate buttons or something click able using c sharp coding ? can anyone give me the code please .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your layout root is `ContentPanel`, what is the default, it would be something like this:

```
    TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
    textBlock.Text = "Ho, ho, ho!";
    ContentPanel.Children.Add(textBlock);
```

Comment: I tried using buttons in code before, and a Width and Height had to be assigned for them to be visible. I'm not sure how to set them to 'Auto' as you can in XAML.